# bat file debug "back up used files"

Tags: batch-file, copy, backup

Here is what I want to do: I want to write a "bat" file that will check all the files in a single partition to determine whether any file is revised/created today and if any, I would copy these file to a folder. So, if I run this bat everyday before I leave my office, I can backup all the files I used in a single folder. The bat file I have now copies the folder instead of file, and sometimes it doesn't work at all... Could you help me debug it? You might want to put it in a root directory such as C/D, and then change d:/test to whatever folder you plan to "test copy the targeted file.

Here is the code I have for now:

```
@echo off
set t=%date%
set t=%t:~0,10%
echo %t%
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d')  do (
set d=%%~ti
set d=!d:~0,10!
echo !d!
if "!d!"=="%t%" (if not "%~nx0"=="%%i" copy "%%i"  d:\test))
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('dir /b /ad') do (
set d=%%~tj
set d=!d:~0,10!
echo !d!
if "!d!"=="%t%"  (echo d|xcopy /e /y "%%j" d:\test\%%j))
```

Comment: you should provide your local date format. What should this `echo d|xcopy` do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `robocopy`?  This line will copy all files in c:\source and its subfolders that have been modified in the last day, to d:\test.

```
robocopy c:\source d:\test *.* /s /maxage:1
```

Of course if you forget to run it one day, you'll miss any files touched that day.  So if this is really for backups, the better approach is to use the Archive bit.

```
robocopy c:\source d:\test *.* /s /m
```

When a file is created or edited, Windows will clear the Archive bit.  `robocopy` with the `/m` switch will only copy files with the Archive bit set (meaning only ones that have changed since the last time you ran your script), then sets the Archive bit.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answered your question, please mark it as Accepted.